# create an index of array inside foreach loop ci

Tags: php

i have an array of id's through which i have to fetch data from two tables basically now let break my issue step by step

First step i have to get the id's of whom i want the data, this is the model that returns data of id's

```
function child_get($id){
        $this->db->select("id");
        $this->db->from('generic_table');
        $this->db->where("parent",$id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

this return an array of ids in the following format

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 13 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 14 ) )
```

i have no issue so far now i have to traverse this array and dynamically add data into array depending on the id's for this i used a foreach loop

```
$arrOfIds = $data['child1'];
          foreach($arrOfIds as $row) {
             $data['child3']=array
            (
                "id" => $row["id"],
                "path" => $this->Menu->test_maindata($row["id"])
            );
          }
```

the model used inside foreach

```
 public function test_maindata($id)
    {
        $this->db->select("path");
        $this->db->from('main_data');
        $this->db->where("f_key",$id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

now the first issue it overriding the every value of iteration and returning only the last value see below

```
Array ( [id] => 14 [path] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [path] => almond.jpg ) ) )
```

you can see it skipped the iteration of id 13

secondly can i make this array in the following pattern

```
Array( [0] => Array( id=> 13, path=>bluebery.jpg) [1]=> Array( id=> 14, path=>almond.jpg));
```

Comment: why you are not using join functionality of CI framework

Comment: i am looking at it but still one issue remains how to i add it on array dynamically as you can see inside the loop it is overriding on every iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
just use this single query and let me know what is output this is giving

    $this->db->select("generic_table.name,main_data.path");
$this->db->from('generic_table');
$this->db->where("generic_table.id",$id);
$this->db->join("main_data","main_data.f_key = generic_table.id");
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
```

and for loop iteration

```
$arrOfIds = $data['child1'];
          foreach($arrOfIds as $row) {
             $data['child3'][]=array
            (
                "id" => $row["id"],
                "path" => $this->Menu->test_maindata($row["id"])
            );
          }
```

Comment: Array ( [id] => 14 [path] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 16 [path] => almond.jpg ) ) )

Comment: the join is somewhere incorrect it is not comparing the id's the id's are 13,14 and it is returning 14,16

Comment: how the tables are related to each other?

Comment: now you have to php coding to show proper path in view file

Comment: alright i got it working it is returning correct array like  Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Almonds [path] => almond.jpg ) )   if i am using $this->Menu->test_maindata("14");

Comment: only thing remains how do i do the same inside a loop and prevent overriding?

Comment: sorry I didn't understand ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144466/discussion-between-uneeb-meer-and-amit-gaud).